# Convert try to option without losing error information in Scala

Tags: scala, try-catch, option-type, scala-2.11

### Introduction

I had created a lovely one-liner:

```
Option("something").map(_ => Try("something else")).flatten.getOrElse("default")
```

which actually does not compile, with error:

```
Error:(15, 31) Cannot prove that scala.util.Try[String] <:< Option[B].
Option("").map(_ => Try("")).flatten.getOrElse("");}
                             ^
```

so I had found a way around:

```
Option("something").flatMap(_ => Try("something else").toOption).getOrElse("default")
```

### But, the problem

My colleague warned me, that my construction is actually loosing the error information. This is true, and in real-life application - not acceptable.

After getting rid of all the repetition I had ended up with:

```
implicit class CoolTry[T](t: Try[T]) extends StrictLogging {
  def toOptionSE: Option[T] = t match {
    case Success(s) => Some(s)
    case Failure(ex) =>
      logger.error(ex.getMessage, ex)
      None
  }
}
```

using:

```
Option("something").flatMap(_ => Try(new Exception("error")).toOptionSE).getOrElse("default")
```

### Question

I believe there are many similar cases in every application and I simply do not know if either my approach is bad or `Try().toOption` is simply done wrong?

I understand that logging is a side effect, but while using `Try` I guess everyone **does** expect it if something goes wrong?

- Can the `implicit` class be improved?
- Is there any utility library handling `Try().toOption` my way?
- Or what (other) approach should I take here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well... if you want to preserve the error, just do not choose Option. It is not the appropriate abstraction for your purpose, stay with Try. Just think about it, how can the Option even preserve the error.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Obviously it will not preserve it. But I believe it should give some side effect if it occurs.

Comment: So... you want to deliberately introduce the "side-effects" (which should actually be avoided) into an otherwise sane environment. Tell me... what is wrong with `Try` ? Do you realise that your requirement is similar to this -> "how can I convert a map into a list which behaves like a map ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing logging every time you change a `Try[T]` to an `Option[T]` is an undesired effect IMO. When you do such a transformation you're explicitly admitting that you don't really care about the internals of the failure, if it happened. All you want is to access the result, if it exists. Most of the time you say "well, this is undesirable, I always want to log exceptions", but sometimes you simply only care about the end result, so dealing with an `Option[T]` can be good enough.

> Or what (other) approach should I take here?

Using `Either[A, B]` is an option here, especially in Scala 2.12 when it became right biased. You can simply map over it and only at the end check if there was an error and then log (created with Scala 2.12.1):

```
val res: Either[Throwable, String] = Option("something")
  .map(_ => Try("something else").toEither)
  .getOrElse(Right("default"))
  .map(str => s"I got my awesome $str")
```

Ideally (IMO) deferring the logging side effect to the last possible point would serve you better.

Comment: can you try to create a one-liner like in the Introduction, using `Either`?

Comment: It would be wise to not overrate one-liners. ;-)

Comment: @Atais Why does it matter if it's a single line or multiple lines of code? I think what's more important is *does it convey what I'm trying to do*.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think what OP means to say is - "Can you provide a one line (read as short) example code for creating Either from a Try and how can I use an Either ?"

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Edited the answer, hope that's what you meant.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov this is more-less what I wanted. Unfortunately, we use `Scala 2.11` in the project and cannot update now. But I will save it for the future :)

Answer (score 3):

One possible improvement would be to make it crystal clear to the user of what is going on; between the `implicit` being injected somewhere by the compiler and the apparently "pure" name (`toOptionSE`) it may not be evident of what is going on for a second developer reading and/or modifying your code. Furthermore, you're fixing how you treat the error case and don't leave the opportunity to handle it differently from logging it.

You can treat errors by leveraging projection, like the `failed` projection defined over `Try`. If you really want to do this fluently and on one line, you can leverage `implicit class`es like this.

```
implicit class TryErrorHandlingForwarding[A](t: Try[A]) {
  def onError(handler: Throwable => Unit): Try[A] = {
    t.failed.foreach(handler)
    t
  }
}

// maybe here you want to have an actual logger
def printStackTrace: Throwable => Unit =
  _.printStackTrace

Option("something").
  flatMap(_ => Try(???).onError(printStackTrace).toOption).
  getOrElse("default")
```

Also, here I'm assuming that for whatever reason you cannot use `Try` right from the start (as it's been suggested in a comment).